# How to allow dragging of links to copy them?

Tags: javascript, iframe

On my website, I have an iframe showing another site, and a couple of textboxes for users to input links in the other frame. I know that some webapps allow for drag copying (such as gmail - you can drag a hyperlink into the body of an email, and it gets rendered properly). Is this possible to implement with javascript, or do I need to use something else?